# Is there a way to activate suppression when not fighting?

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

When you are in the Matrix and already have some system trace on you, is it possible to reduce it by activating suppression without fighting someone?

Comment: I just finished the game as decker and apparently there is no way to do that.

Comment: You can write an answer to your own question and set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finishing the game playing as a Decker, it seems clear to me that it's not possible to activate suppression when not fighting.

Somehow, it makes sense. When you are not fighting, there are no action points, so you would be able to zero the warning level. That would make the entire experience way too easy.